# Remove images at runtime, only remove one image on two

Tags: vb.net

I've got a `form1`, a `textbox1` and 2 buttons, `Bt_Draw` and `Bt_Clear`.

The user input a number in `textbox1` and click on `Bt_Draw`, this will create X `PictureBox` on `Form1` (where X is the input number and the image is from a resource file).

If the user click on `Bt_Clear` this should clear all the `PictureBox` eventually present.

The issue that I have is that, when I click on `Bt_Clear` it only clear one `PictureBox`on two, like this :

[image]

This is my code :

`Bt_Draw` event : (this one works fine)

```
Private Sub Bt_Draw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_Draw.Click

    Dim insertX As Long = 150 'image coordinate
    Dim insertY As Long = 250

    For i = 1 To Integer.Parse(Me.TextBox1.Text)

        Dim Img As New PictureBox

        With Img
            .Size = New Size(20, 20)
            .Location = New Point(insertX, insertY)
            .Image = My.Resources.Resource1.Image1 'image1 in recource1.resx
            .Name = "Roll" & i
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(Img)
        insertX = insertX + 20

    Next
End Sub
```

The `Bt_Clear` event :

```
Private Sub Bt_Del_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_Del.Click

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Dim pb = TryCast(ctrl, PictureBox)

        If pb IsNot Nothing Then
            If pb.Name.Contains("Roll") Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(pb)
            End If
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I have also try some more techniques to suppress all `PictureBox` with the same result.

While debugging it seems that the `For Each ctrl In Me.Controls` loop do not return all the controls. How can I fix this, and why do this code behave like this ?

Comment: You have to `Dispose()` of the Control, not `Remove()` it. When you dispose of the Control, it will also be removed from the collection it belongs to (`Remove()` doesn't dispose of the object). You're also modifying the collection you're iterating by removing elements in a `For Each` loop. You can iterate, for example, `For Each pBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).ToList()`. But a backwards `For` loop is maybe simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you remove the controls while you iterate them. You can use a solution like the following to collect the controls and [remove the collected controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-to-or-remove-from-a-collection-of-controls-at-run-time#to-remove-controls-from-a-collection-programmatically) in a separate step.

```vb
'A list to collect all controls you want to remove.
Dim listRemoveControls As New List(Of PictureBox)

'get all controls you want to remove and collect them on the list.
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Dim pb = TryCast(ctrl, PictureBox)

    If pb IsNot Nothing Then
        If pb.Name.Contains("Roll") Then
            listRemoveControls.Add(pb)
        End If
    End If
Next

'now you can remove the controls collected in the list.
For Each pbItem As PictureBox In listRemoveControls
    If Me.Controls.Contains(pbItem) Then
        Me.Controls.Remove(pbItem)
        pbItem.Dispose()
    End If
Next
```

In case you can use Linq (.NET >= 3.5), the following solution using [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) is much shorter:

```vb
For Each pbItem As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).ToList()
    If Me.Controls.Contains(pbItem) Then
        Me.Controls.Remove(pbItem)
        pbItem.Dispose()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You just need this:  `For Each pBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).ToList() pBox?.Dispose() Next`. Please, don't use `Remove()`.